# XCode 11 crash after adding iOS 14 device support

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode11, ios14

My XCode version is 11.1 and the iPhone OS version is 14.0.1. To run apps on iOS 14
device, it requires XCode 12.

An alternate option to support iOS 14 in XCode 11, is to add Device Support. So I have added Device Support for iOS 14 in the following way -

Goto Applications > Xcode > Right Click > Show Package Contents > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport

Then added the device support files in this directory.

Device Support files are available here - https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

After adding Device support, whenever I try to run it on the iPhone device, it instantly shows a 'Build Successful' message, then XCode crashes.

Here is the build error log -

```
Process:               Xcode [1314]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               11.1 (15405)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-15405000000000000~13
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       832925179
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1314]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-03-31 20:33:14.126 +0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G95)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.6 (16P6571)
Anonymous UUID:        13DE45B0-BCED-AB3D-BEDF-B4704CEFE0C2


Time Awake Since Boot: 630 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        18  Dispatch queue: Mutex to protect _hasPerformedWorkerAction

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
com.apple.main-thread
ProductBuildVersion: 11A1027
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Calling block provided to DVTSyncPerformBlock() here:
 
  0   DVTSyncPerformBlock (in DVTFoundation)
  1   -[IDEExecutionRunnableTracker executionWantsHold:withError:] (in IDEFoundation)
  2   -[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:] (in IDEFoundation)
  3   __44-[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:]_block_invoke_3 (in IDEFoundation)
  4   __48-[DVTDispatchLock_Recursive performLockedBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  5   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6   _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
  8   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  9   -[DVTDispatchLock_Recursive performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 10   __44-[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
 11   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
 12   __DVTDispatchAfter_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 13   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15   _dispatch_source_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)
 17   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 18   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 19   _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 20   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 21   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 
Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] (in Foundation)
  5   -[NSCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:] (in AppKit)
  6   -[NSCell setStringValue:] (in AppKit)
  7   -[NSControl setStringValue:] (in AppKit)
  8   -[IDEExecutionHoldAlertHelper showAlert] (in IDEKit)
  9   -[IDEWorkspaceTabController showExecutionHoldAlertWithError:] (in IDEKit)
 10   __55-[IDEWorkspaceDocument _setupLaunchSessionsObservation]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEKit)
 11   -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
 12   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
 13   NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
 14   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 15   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 16   _NSSetCharValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
 17   -[IDEExecutionTracker _updateWantsHold] (in IDEFoundation)
 18   __37-[IDEExecutionTracker addSubtracker:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 19   -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
 20   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
 21   NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
 22   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 23   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 24   _NSSetCharValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
 25   __60-[IDEExecutionRunnableTracker executionWantsHold:withError:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 26   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
 27   __DVTSyncPerformBlock_block_invoke.48 (in DVTFoundation)
 28   DVTInvokeWithLazyFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 29   __DVTSyncPerformBlock_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 30   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
 31   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
 32   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 33   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 34   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 35   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 36   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 37   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 38   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 39   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 40   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 41   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 42   main (in Xcode)
 43   start (in libdyld.dylib)
 
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInternalInconsistencyException
```

Comment: Why not just do this the right way and use Xcode 12?

Comment: Hi @matt, Upgrading XCode or Mac OS is not possible due to some security reason. That is why I am trying with existing resources.

Comment: I have upgraded my iPhone OS to 14.4.2. Now I have been facing another problem when trying to run from Xcode 11, it shows 'Unable to copy symbols from this device'.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a security enhancement that stops Xcode 11 working with iOS 14 (the probable underlying reason causing the crash) but there is a workaround (and lots of other helpful information) at https://betterprogramming.pub/debugging-on-ios-14-with-xcode-11-d332f12f49dd which explains how to launch, log and debug.

Comment: I've had that kind of problem myself.  Try out https://stackoverflow.com/a/39029595/2715565 to see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. I have tried all of this but doesn't work. I have been facing this problem 'Unable to copy symbols from this device'. Smilar problem https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/issues/134

Comment: One way to narrow it down is to pull off the console logs from the phone.  If you can do that and share the console messages at the time of the problem, it could point to where the problem is.  Also, is your cable an Apple-manufactured one, and is it directly connected to the computer (no hubs)?  It can be glitchy if otherwise.